# Can i hide a viewbag if a fieldtext is not empty?

Tags: c#

For example, i have a viewbag showing a error message if a field is empty. Can it be hide if something is written there ?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(label)){

     ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The field is empty!";

}else{

     ViewBag.ErrorMessage = false;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try?  Having the same property sometimes be a `string` and sometimes a `bool` probably isn't a great idea.  Maybe just set it to an empty string?  Or don't set it at all?  What displays in the view will depend more on how you consume this data than how you set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(label))
{
     ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The field is empty!";

}
else
{

     ViewBag.ErrorMessage = null;
}
```

In your razor:

```
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
 // display message here
}
```